# Break string where character exists and push new items into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Let's say I have this string:

`$city = 'New York/Paris/Berlin/Osaka'`

Is there any way to break the variable where `/` exists and push every city into an array using PHP?

I would post an example, but I have no idea about how to do this. I am a beginner and I didn't find any way to do this on Google.

My script is more complicated, I get `$city` from a MySQL database, but this is the simple way so you will understand what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of **`explode()`** in PHP

```
<?php
$city = "New York/Paris/Berlin/Osaka";
print_r(explode('/',$city));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => New York
    [1] => Paris
    [2] => Berlin
    [3] => Osaka
)
```

Alternatively, you can access like `$city[0], $city[1] , ...`